# Change query value based on parameter

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a query:

```
doc.NonFinancialAssetSection.NonFinancialAssets
              .Where(m => m.Owner.Id == ownerId && m.InvestableAsset == true)
              .Sum(s => s.CurrentValue);
```

I need to change the value of s.CurrentValue to s.ProposedValue, however rather than copying and pasting the query again, is there any way i can have this value dependant on a parameter passed into the controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this:

```
var query = doc.NonFinancialAssetSection.NonFinancialAssets
                .Where(m => m.Owner.Id == ownerId && m.InvestableAsset == true);

var sum = (condition) 
     ? query.Sum(s => s.CurrentValue) 
     : query.Sum(s => s.ProposedValue);
```

You could also do this:

```
var sum = doc.NonFinancialAssetSection.NonFinancialAssets
             .Where(m => m.Owner.Id == ownerId && m.InvestableAsset == true)
             .Sum(s => (condition) ? s.CurrentValue : s.ProposedValue);
```

Or this:

```
Func<NonFinancialAsset, double> sumProperty = (condition)
     ? s => s.CurrentValue
     : s => s.ProposedValue;

var sum = doc.NonFinancialAssetSection.NonFinancialAssets
             .Where(m => m.Owner.Id == ownerId && m.InvestableAsset == true)
             .Sum(sumProperty);
```